# What manufacturer and model SSD drive are in the Early 2011 MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

Thinking about getting the new MBP but cannot decide if the SSD upgrade is worth it; $100 dollars to bump to the 128 is small money but SSD drives vary widely in performance. trying to decide if I spend the $100 with apple or pick something better up at NewEgg.

Comment: Are you referring to the 2011 ones?

Comment: i don't see an answer to my question in there

Comment: The question is not answered there, but that doesn't mean that we should have two of them. People will answer the original if they can.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Anandtech](http://www.anandtech.com/show/2829/19) it's a Samsung brand SSD.

> The largest SSD maker in the world is Samsung. Samsung makes the drives offered by Apple in its entire MacBook/MacBook Pro lineup. Samsung makes the drives you get if you order a Lenovo X300. In fact, if you're buying any major OEM system with an SSD in it, Samsung makes that drive.

I spoke with a few of the guys at work that replace these and they told me that they don't really pay attention to the brands, It's OEM. But the ones that he could remember where Samsung and Seagate.

Now this doesn't speak to the brand that ships, but just what is replaced (if needed) when you bring it in for repair.

Comment: That was is 2009.

Comment: Very true, but Samsung is still the largest supplier of SSD. Until I can get in to work tomorrow and ask one of my co-workers for a 100% answer it's the best one I can provide.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation would be to not spend the money on the SSD from Apple and get the standard drive that it comes with. As well as Apple typically places a premium price on parts from them.

Then you have the time to research the best SSD for your needs and at your own leisure pace. You will also have the original HDD to fall back to if you ever need it.

Or you could choose to remove the optical drive and install a drive cage and use both the SSD and HDD. I think that OWC sells a cage for that option.

Comment: True, true. Even more true for RAM. Apple charges (at least in my experience) **ten times more** than others (OWC, Crucial).

Comment: The ram upgrade to 8gb is not that bad (relative to the above quote); DDR3 1333 for 8gb parts on NewEgg right now runs roughly 100 when you include shipping/tax. Apple wants $200 for the upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

Toshiba in the MacPros, and according to anandtech, the MacBookAir has the same controller as the Kingston, which is by Toshiba.  No reason they'd still be using samsung
http://www.anandtech.com/show/3991/apples-2010-macbook-air-11-13inch-reviewed/4
[image]